# Using two 6pin connectors on a GTX 770 which has sockets for a 6 pin and an 8 pin

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

My friend has an MSI GTX 770 graphics card and a 850w power supply by a company called Pulse Power. The 770 has power sockets for a 6 pin and an 8 pin cable but there is only cables for two 6 pins available from the PSU. There is another 8 pin cable, but it's currently connected to the motherboard.

Would it be possible to use the two 6 pin cables with the GPU or would this not draw enough power for the card? Or would we need to get a [molex to 8 pin converter](https://www.kenable.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=6337) instead as there is also a spare molex cable from the PSU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the PSU the 6 and 8 pin connectors are different so it probably won't fit, even if it does the card won't be able to work properly cause its not getting enough power.

Buy the adapter and you won't have any problems, they are really cheap, but bear in mind you will need two spare 4 pin molex connections.

Comment: Anecdotally: I was lacking an appropriate 8-pin pcie connector also, but my video card had a dual-molex adapter in the box. It works, no problem.

Comment: Yeh there are enough molex cables spare if we were to use one with the converter on the GPU. I just wasn't sure if converting it from molex would cause any damage. Thank you for your reply though, we'll hold out and wait to get one before trying it!